# What best solution for prevent browser cache file in react

Tags: reactjs, web, caching

My problem is
when I deploy new version react web  to production
some user browser display old version from previous deploy
My user have to  press ctrl+f5 for clear cache browser then I think  which bad  solution
please suggest best solution for me  thx bro.

Comment: If you used create react app, then every time you take a build, webpack will generate files with different hashes in the filename. This ensures that you can have even a large cache setting but it will still request the new bundle since the name is different. Are you doing something different, like service worker?

Comment: @KennyJohnJacob  
serviceWorker.unregister() this  code  at last line  index.js  so i think i not use service worker

Comment: Could you elaborate on your hosting provider? If index.html has a large cache duration, then you may experience the same issue. Try to give no-cache for index.html

Comment: @ My web is intranet web app for use in my company .  I start host server by node js docker

Comment: For your website, could you check in dev tools for index.html what the value is for the Response Header `cache-control`?

Comment: How check i try  see in network tab of  chrome dev tool But not show  index.html  row

remark 
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />

this script  at top   index.html

Comment: Open the network tab and hit refresh, it should show all the requests, just ensure that you don't have any filters applied

Answer (score 2):

This could be because your web server is setting a cache control response header, which is set to a large value. Could you check the value in devtools?

[image: cache-control sample]

A simple explanation of what cache control does is it tells the browser that the browser can use the cached resource upto n minutes. So only after n minutes will the browser send a new request for the resource.

Since you have a react app (a web app), the browser requests for index.html, and it will subsequently fetch the js bundle for your react app.

When you push an updated version, the browser doesn't know that there is an update. Since the index.html was cached, it continues to use it. Until the cache time expires, and then it will fetch again and this time it will get the latest js bundle.

Based on your server, you will need to figure out how to set the `cache-control` header for index.html to be of value `no-cache`. Here is an example of how I set it up in firebase hosting,

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/service-worker.js",
        "headers": [{ "key": "Cache-Control", "value": "no-cache" }]
      },
      {
        "source": "/index.html",
        "headers": [{ "key": "Cache-Control", "value": "no-cache" }]
      },
      {
        "source": "/static/**/*",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=31536000"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Since create react app automatically configures the webpack build to generate static files with different hashes in the filename, it is fine to set a large cache value for it.

Answer (score 0):

That occurs because, by default, the service workers do cache, so you should check your react project *index.js* file and check to see if services workers are registered. *serviceWorker.register()*.

If it is registered then Unregister the service worker *serviceWorker.unregister()*.

The above being quite drastic as a method, since it could affect your user experience what is recommended is that you configure your PWA to suit your particular caching needs. Follow this resource "https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker" for more about playing with service workers.

In case you need caching for your application, your backend sends appropriate response headers.